# Is there a way to pass additional data to UserInfo dictionary using NSNotificationCenter with UIKeyboardDidShowNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios8, keyboard, xcode6

I have these lines of code:

```
-(void)someMethod:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
// I want to get scrollView over here
}
```

Is there a way to make this possible? I've tried to perform this staff according to

> [How to pass a NSDictionary with postNotificationName:object:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127284/how-to-pass-a-nsdictionary-with-postnotificationnameobject)

but aNotification.userInfo doesn't contain my data

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
postNotificationName:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
object:self
 userInfo:@{@"scrollView":scrollView}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening to `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and then you post `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` that won't work. First maybe you like create your own notification name i.e `XYZKeyboardDidShowNotification` and then register for that and post using that name with the additional data you want. And then you can do:

```
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = aNotification.userInfo[@"scrollView"];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use default UIKeyboardDidShowNotification?

Comment: Well. Your answer can't help with my question because question was really dumb. Thanks to you I've made own custom notification and have found mistakes in architecture of my classes.